# Move a document to a folder that someone else shared with me

Tags: file-sharing, onedrive

A coworker has shared a OneDrive folder with me. How, if at all, can I add a document in that folder?

It seems like the only way to do this is as follows:

1. Go to the folder that's someone has shared with me (e.g. Shared > SomeFolder)
2. Choose Create > SomeDocument

Now that document is within the shared folder. It doesn't seem like I can move an existing document to a folder that someone else has shared with me. Can we?

Comment: you can add OneDrive desktop app to your (Windows) computer and use it to manage that folder. You should then be able to click and drag existing files. If that's a sloution you're looking for I'll add it as an answer. https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-nz/download/

Comment: Yes. Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

With a free Microsoft account you can add the OneDrive desktop app to your (Windows) computer and use it to manage that folder. The One Drive desktop app will sync with the web app.

You should then be able to click and drag existing files from your local computer, and access them from anywhere on the web. As long as your co-worker has added you as an editor to that folder.

The curent download link is located here:

[onedrive.live.com/about/en-nz/download](http://onedrive.live.com/about/en-nz/download)

---

You should be able to click and drag from your local machine to white space inside a shared folder. It works in Chrome.

Comment: When I look at the OneDrive Desktop app, I can only see the folders that I own not those that others have shared with me.